# Trying to hide jframe in java but my code doesn't work?

Tags: java

Right so it's not working, I also tried setVisible(False) that said something about can't make static reference to boolean or something like that.
Here's my code can you please help me fix this? I won't have time to make major so small changes if possible to make it work thank you.
To make your life easier so you don't read my whole code just do ctrl + f"okbtn"

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;


/**
* This code was edited or generated using CloudGarden's Jigloo
* SWT/Swing GUI Builder, which is free for non-commercial
* use. If Jigloo is being used commercially (ie, by a corporation,
* company or business for any purpose whatever) then you
* should purchase a license for each developer using Jigloo.
* Please visit www.cloudgarden.com for details.
* Use of Jigloo implies acceptance of these licensing terms.
* A COMMERCIAL LICENSE HAS NOT BEEN PURCHASED FOR
* THIS MACHINE, SO JIGLOO OR THIS CODE CANNOT BE USED
* LEGALLY FOR ANY CORPORATE OR COMMERCIAL PURPOSE.
*/
public class MainMenu extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private JLabel username;
    private JLabel passwordlbl;
    private JLabel Welco;
    private JButton Cancelbtn;
    private JButton OKbtn;
    private JTextField Usernametxt;
    double ss;

    /**
    * Auto-generated main method to display this JFrame
    */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //PASSWORD field to store new password inside
        //Passwordfld.setEchoChar('*');
        //Passwordfld.addActionListener(new AL());

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MainMenu inst = new MainMenu();
                inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                inst.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    public MainMenu() {
        super();
        initGUI();

    }
    private static boolean isPasswordCorrect(char[] input) {
        boolean isCorrect = true;
        char[] correctPassword = { 'b', 'u', 'g', 'a', 'b', 'o', 'o' };

        if (input.length != correctPassword.length) {
            isCorrect = false;
        } else {
            isCorrect = Arrays.equals (input, correctPassword);
        }

        //Zero out the password.
        Arrays.fill(correctPassword,'0');

        return isCorrect;
    }
    private void initGUI() {
        try {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            getContentPane().setLayout(null);
            getContentPane().setBackground(new java.awt.Color(11,101,149));

            username = new JLabel();
            getContentPane().add(username);
            username.setText("User Name:");
            username.setBounds(63, 113, 80, 16);

            passwordlbl = new JLabel();
            getContentPane().add(passwordlbl);
            passwordlbl.setText("Password:");
            passwordlbl.setBounds(63, 160, 72, 16);

            Usernametxt = new JTextField();
            getContentPane().add(Usernametxt);
            Usernametxt.setBounds(198, 110, 79, 23);

            final JPasswordField Passwordfld = new JPasswordField();
            // Passwordfld.setText("Secret");
            getContentPane().add(Passwordfld);
            Passwordfld.setBounds(198, 157, 79, 23);
            Passwordfld.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // System.out.println("Passwordfld.actionPerformed, event="+evt);
                // TODO add your code for Passwordfld.actionPerformed
            }
            });
            OKbtn = new JButton();
            getContentPane().add(OKbtn);
            OKbtn.setText("OK");
            OKbtn.setBounds(102, 217, 59, 23);
            OKbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                String passText = new String(Passwordfld.getPassword());

                String cmd = evt.getActionCommand();
                /*This where the the majority of the code is executed
                Once the user types his info in and clicks the "ok button" the code is then executed and then depending 
                if the user gets his info correct the system communicates with the user allowing them to know if they
                succeeded in logging in.*/
                if (OKbtn.getActionCommand().equals(cmd)) { // Process the password.
                    if (Usernametxt.getText().equals("Admin")&& (isPasswordCorrect(passText.toCharArray()))) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainMenu.this,
                                "Password Accepted");
                        System.out.println("Password Accepted");
                        ItemsPage ItemsPage = new ItemsPage(ss);
                        this.setVisible(false);
                        ItemsPage.setVisible(true);

                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainMenu.this,
                                "Password Rejected");
                    System.out.println("Password Rejected: " + passText);

                    }

                    // Zero out the possible password, for security.
                    Arrays.fill(passText.toCharArray(), '0');

                    Passwordfld.selectAll();

                    /*
                     * else{ System.out.println("permition Rejected"); }
                     */

                    // else{}
                    /*
                     * if (Passwordfld = Password)= true) {
                     * System.out.println("permition granted");}
                     */
                }

            }

            private void setVisible(boolean b) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            });

            Cancelbtn = new JButton();
            getContentPane().add(Cancelbtn);
            Cancelbtn.setText("Exit");
            Cancelbtn.setBounds(198, 217, 61, 23);
            Cancelbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                System.exit(0);//shuts down the program
                    //System.out.println("Cancelbtn.actionPerformed, event="+evt);
                    //TODO add your code for Cancelbtn.actionPerformed
                }
            });

            Welco = new JLabel();
            getContentPane().add(Welco);
            Welco.setText("Welcome to Jstore please log in using your staff acount");
            Welco.setBounds(51, 19, 291, 16);





            pack();
            setSize(400, 300);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //add your error handling code here
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    //static class AL implements ActionListener{
    //JPasswordField input = new JPasswordField();

    /*  char [] passy = input.getPassword();
        String p = new String (passy);{
        if (p.equals (Password)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct"); }
            else
            {       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "InCorrect");

        }
        */


    }
```

Comment: i'm not asking for code reviewing I want to know what the mistake is + if I can do anything to fix it or if anyone willing to give me a hand with this, thanks for the thumbs down.

Comment: I have done plenty of research btw and looked at various stuff but the stuff I saw non of them have worked for me.

Comment: @Andremoniy well the place for code review questions would be on [codereview.se], but if the code doesn't work as intended, it's not ready for peer review, it's off-topic on CR and on-topic on SO. Upvoted.

Comment: Try moving the setVisible() to the bottom of initGUI()

Comment: @Dan        pack();
            setSize(400, 300);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //add your error handling code here
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.setVisible(false);
    } Don't get the redline anymore but it doesn't hide it either :(

Comment: Swing renders off in its own thread.  You are trying to race it to drawing the components.  You'll need to change the order in which you create, pack and configure things.

Comment: Try removing `private void setVisible(boolean b) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }` right after your `actionPerformed` method. This method shadows the `setVisible(boolean b)` in `JFrame` which does the showing and hiding for you. Showing your frame does work because you do it with `inst.setVisible(true);` which can't invoke a private method.

Comment: @Frank removed the private void setVIisible, only reason I created that because eclipse suggested doing that will fix it, still nothing doesn't work.

Comment: @Dan how do you recommend I do that? do you mind showing me maybe with few example? thanks a lot.

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. You code is difficult to read since the forum highlight all variable names the same as a class name. Fix the code and update your posting.